# Is Google translate API return any data about translated word verification?

Tags: google-translate

It's important for me to identify, is a word verified.

[What I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZFSs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be available. If you check the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate#response-body) for the body of a response to the API's `translate` method, there's no field indicating that the translation is checked by the Community (which is what this little badge next to the translated text implies).